# Normalization of several time-series of different lengths and scale

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Say I have several random time-series in numpy, e.g.:

```
my_time_series = dict()
for L in range(20,50,10):
   scaling = np.random.randint(100)
   my_time_series[L] = scaling * np.random.rand(L) + scaling * np.random.rand(L)
```

I would like to **normalize** them **in scale and length** so that can I visualize them and compare changes over time. To do this, one approach would be the following:

1. Normalization in **scale**: Apply [Z-standarization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score)
2. Normalization in **length**: Stretch (interpolate) the shorter time-series to the length of the longest one, so that they all have the same length.

**Motivation:** I am mostly interested in comparing the **relative variability** of the time-series over their lifespan (regardless of how long they are).

How can I do this in numpy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
y_normed = {k: (data-np.mean(data))/np.std(data) 
            for k, data in my_time_series.items()}

maxlength = max(my_time_series)
x_interped = {k: np.interp(np.linspace(0, 1, maxlength), 
                           np.linspace(0, 1, k), data) 
              for k, data in y_normed.items()}

[plot(data) for data in x_interped.values()]
```

[image: plot of data]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Can we normalize this way to forecast time series in different scales?